# Make child elements overflow in parent container

Tags: html, css

How do I make child elements overflow if their width is greater than parent's width?
As you can see, below in the code the `.container` width is 600px while every div inside has width 200px, so the total width is 1200px. Why aren't the divs inside `.container` overflow?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `width`.

Use flex properties on the children and `max-width` on the container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container div {
  flex: 0 0 200px;

  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` on child divs instead of `width`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container div {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
    <div>child</div>
  </div>
</body>
```